# Measuring second excited state |2> using "calibrations" not Open Pulse

Tags: programming, qiskit, measurement, openpulse

I am tying to measure the second excited state in a system that does not support Open Pulse. Instead I am using [calibrations](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits_advanced/05_pulse_gates.html). The method detailed [here](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/accessing_higher_energy_states.html) does not work. I get the error  `"AttributeError: 'IBMQBackend' object has no attribute 'instruction_schedule_map'"`.

Using the method detailed [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.pulse.builder.measure.html) reproduces the same error `"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'instruction_schedule_map'"`.

Is there a different way to access the measurement calibrations in a system which does not support pulse?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on my own. In case someone has a similar problem:

You can use the standard measure() function in the quantum circuit. When you assemble you can specify meas_level=1 which returns the raw measured data without running it through a classifier. Then you can build your own classifier.